# Change Finder folder view for only one folder?

Tags: macos, finder, folders

Is it possible to, for example, set icon view to be the view for just *one specific folder* in Finder? It seems as though if I set a folder to icon view (currently the default is list view), opening folders inside that folder cause the opened folder to change to icon view as well. However, I don't want this to happen – I only want to affect the folder that I changed it for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go into the folder and choose the view you want the folder to display as. Press <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>, then check the "Always open in [type] view" box at the top of the small window and make sure that the "Browse in [type] view" option is unchecked. Close that window. Now the Finder should switch the view to the one you chose whenever you enter that folder.

Comment: `cmd+J` is same as `view->show view options` in the menu. For people who do not want to remember keyboard shortcuts, this is the way to do using the mouse cursor